# How can I put 2nd level accordion by using ionic and angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to do one level of accordion using angularjs but I want one more level, please help me how can I do this..

How do I create a multiple-level (embedded) accordian using Angular?

The layout should have collable sections with this hierarchy:

Controller.js...

```
ctrl.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.groups = [];
          for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            $scope.groups[i] = {
              name: i,
              items: []
            };
            for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
              $scope.groups[i].items.push("Doctor" + '-' + j);
            }

          }
          $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
            if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
              $scope.shownGroup = null;
            } else {
              $scope.shownGroup = group;
            }
          };
          $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
            return $scope.shownGroup === group;
          };

        });
```

test.html...

```
<ion-list id = "background" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div id = "background" ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <ion-item class="item-stable item item-avatar" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
            <img ng-src = "img/1.png"/>
            Clinic {{group.name}}
            &nbsp;
            <p>Address:</p> 
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item class="item-accordion"
            ng-repeat="item in group.items"
            ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
            {{item}}
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
```